# Error while using NDSolve: number of constraints inadequate

Tags: differential-equations

I am getting the error

```
NDSolve::ndnco: The number of constraints (2) (initial conditions) is not equal to the total differential order of the system plus the number of discrete variables (3).
```

on running the following piece of code:

```
bconds = {
   \[Lambda]'[s] == 0,
   \[Kappa][-1] == 0,
   \[Kappa][1] == 0
   };
sol = NDSolve[{\[Kappa]''[s] + 
      0.5*\[Kappa][s]^3 + \[Lambda][s]*\[Kappa][s] == 0, 
    bconds}, {\[Kappa], \[Lambda]}, s];
```

But I don't get why. I have given three BC's as required. Why is it saying 2?

I have followed the example given here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html#3518691

Comment: The first equation in `bconds` is not a BC. It’s a differential equation.  Perhaps the `s` is meant to be a number?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am just following the usage given in the link. I want to find the value of the unknown eigenvalue `Lambda`, and for that, the link says to add the condition `Lambda'(s) = 0`. In other words, it's treating `Lambda` as a variable of constant value.

Comment: `a'[t] == 0` is not a boundary condition in the example. That example has a 3rd-order ODE and a 1st-order ODE (`a'[t] == 0`) for a total differential order of 4.  It also has 4 BCs.  Hence the example works. You need a 3rd BC on kappa, then, if there is to be none on lambda.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Aaaaaaah! Thank you so much for pointing that out. So I need one extra BC to find the value of the parameter `Lambda`. Got it!